# How do I create a half bottom panel upon a button click?

Tags: flutter

I want to know how to replicate this slide-up widget in Flutter when I click a button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final product :https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW6Xh.jpg
(Stack Overflow won't let me post pictures)

Here is a code example using a variation of the starting app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

//this is the custom function
showTextAreaSheet(BuildContext context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context, 
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom), //keeps above keyboard
              child: const TextField(                
                autofocus:true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "New Task",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ) );      
   
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(        
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Press button to open Text Area',
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {showTextAreaSheet(context);},
          
        
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

I am using a showModalBottomSheet function that I call through the `showTextAreaSheet(BuildContext context)`.

The important part is the padding around the TextField that keeps the text field above the keyboard at all times.

Answer (score 1):

it's called Bottom Sheet
Here is an [example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)